# Grails, submit form in modal with ajax

Tags: ajax, forms, grails, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

Right now I can render a signup form in a twitter bootstrap modal, enter data into it, if the data doesn't pass constraints, the form will render correctly and say that the constraints don't pass (via error messages).

But the problem is, the formRemote that I'm using ends up "passing" even though the constraints aren't validated and the view I get contains the error message.

Essentially, I create a modal, then have it's `data-remote` set to the gsp containing this code:

```
<%@ page import="security.User" %>
<html>
    <head>
        <r:layoutResources />
        <g:set var="entityName" value="${message(code: 'user.label', default: 'User')}" />
        <title><g:message code="default.create.label" args="[entityName]" /></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <g:hasErrors bean="${userInstance}">
        <ul class="errors" role="alert">
            <g:eachError bean="${userInstance}" var="error">
            <li <g:if test="${error in org.springframework.validation.FieldError}">data-field-id="${error.field}"</g:if>><g:message error="${error}"/></li>
            </g:eachError>
        </ul>
        </g:hasErrors>
        <g:formRemote name="ajaxSignupForm" url="[action:'save',controller:'user']" update="signupModal .modal-body">
            <div class="fieldcontain ${hasErrors(bean: userInstance, field: 'username', 'error')} required">
                <label for="username">
                    <g:message code="user.username.label" default="Username" />
                    <span class="required-indicator">*</span>
                </label>
                <g:textField name="username" required="" value="${userInstance?.username}"/>
            </div>

            <div class="fieldcontain ${hasErrors(bean: userInstance, field: 'password', 'error')} required">
                <label for="password">
                    <g:message code="user.password.label" default="Password" />
                    <span class="required-indicator">*</span>
                </label>
                <g:passwordField name="password" required="" value="${userInstance?.password}"/>
            </div>

            <div class="fieldcontain ${hasErrors(bean: userInstance, field: 'confirmPassword', 'error')} required">
                <label for="confirmPassword">
                    <g:message code="user.confirmPassword.label" default="Confirm Password" />
                    <span class="required-indicator">*</span>
                </label>
                <g:passwordField name="confirmPassword" required="" value="${userInstance?.confirmPassword}"/>
            </div>
            <g:submitButton name="create" class="btn btn-success" value="Create Account" />
        </g:formRemote>


            <div style='display: none; text-align: left;' id='signupMessage'></div>
        <r:layoutResources />
    </body>
</html>
```

The `update="signupModal .modal-body"` chunk is what is updating the modal that this gsp is contained in. I understand that this is some nasty logic, so what can I do to make this better and actually perform correctly?

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to enclose your formRemote inside a div.  and then set the update="formParent".

E.g.

```
<div id="formParent" ... update="signupModal">
   <g:formRemote
   ...
</div>
```